# Debian adb connected but device not show up

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, debian, adb

[[image: android studio terminal device connected]]In device terminal is showed up but in device chooser device is not showed.

[image]

**More information:**

- Debian 8 :- latest (updated fresh install)
- android studio :- latest
- android Sdk :- latest
- device updated , rebooted and works fine on windows machine.

this problem comes after connecting android phone via this command

any help appreciated .

***adb connect ###.###.###.###***

Comment: Have you enabled USB debugging on the device?

Answer (score 0):

Three things to consider:

1. On your device you should have the option "USB debugging" enabled.
2. Ensure the connection really works. With the command `lsusb` you can see if the device was detected.
3. In case you have permission problems I would try to open it as root. If that works take a look at the udev permissions.

Comment: device is connected via wifi lsusb does not work here